# BPY - material_slot_remove() - Wrong Context

Tags: python, scripting

I am setting the active object in Blender 3.2 and selecting the corresponding material slots, but when I call material_slot_remove(), it deletes those indices from the previously selected object

Anyone can spot what I am doing wrong? If I select an axis type of object, the script won't execute at all stating that the context is wrong

Executing this script another time immediately afterwards will delete the correct material slots

```
class OP_MaterialCleanUp(bpy.types.Operator): 
    '''Merge material slots and delete unnecessary ones'''
    
    bl_idname = 'opr.matslot'
    bl_label = 'Material Clean Up Operator'
    
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        obj = bpy.context.scene.mainchar #object passed through from a PointerProperty
        print(bpy.context.active_object.name) #states the initially selected object
        
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
        
        print(bpy.context.active_object.name) #states the correct object
        
        
        for mat in reversed(obj.material_slots):
            if mat.name not in mats_to_keep_mainchar:
                obj.active_material_index = mat.slot_index
                
                bpy.context.object.active_material_index = mat.slot_index
                
                bpy.ops.object.material_slot_select()
                print("Selected! ", mat.slot_index, " , ", mat.name, mat) #prints the correct material slot name
                bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove() #removes the indices from the previously selected material slots

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Any thoughts are highly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean axis type of object? As in an *Empty Axis*?

Comment: "Empty" -> "Plain Axes" is what I've meant precisely. Apologies for being unclear. The point was that whenever anything other than a mesh is selected, prior to executing the script, it gives the "wrong context error", even though my script should change both, selection and active object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the materials are stored on the object data, not on the object itself, you can access the list of materials with `obj.data.materials`. [Link to bpy.types.Mesh doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.materials) and [IDMaterials](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.IDMaterials.html#bpy.types.IDMaterials) class members.

Traverse the material list in reversed order and pop the materials you want to remove.

```
for i, mat in reversed(list(enumerate(obj.data.materials)))::
    if mat not in mats_to_keep:
        obj.data.materials.pop(index=i)
```

This will also remove material slots with no material.

Comment: Isn't it a bit more Pythonic to do `for i, mat in reversed(list(enumerate(obj.data.materials))):`

Comment: @Jakemoyo agreed, although the syntax can be a bit confusing for newcomers

Comment: Yeah, you have to be "clued in" to get it for sure, but otherwise you have to read the documentation of the range keyword to understand what the `(..., -1, -1, -1)` arguments are doing exactly. With this at least all the info is there, you just have to break it down. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, but not very pretty:

Just separate the code into the main class (where the selecting and activating happens) and a function (where the material slot deletion process is meant to happen). By using a timer, call the function after some delay and it works just fine

Seems to be a timing issue, any better - more elegant - way of fixing this?

Edit #1: It doesn't work with time.sleep

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of answers but idk if they necessarily address the root issue behind your question. I think the problem is that you aren't being consistent in the object you are referencing. If you want to execute the operator on the active object, then use context argument from the execute method and reference that.

You keep switching between `bpy.data.objects[obj.name]`, `bpy.context.scene.mainchar` and `bpy.context.active_object` and `bpy.context.object` which could almost theoretically be 3 different objects at once. I think that is causing issues.

There are also some other issues in your code I corrected and added notes to.

```
# Operators are supposed to follow this naming convention
# see https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/class-naming-conventions-in-blender-2-8-python-api/

class OBJECT_OT_material_slot_cleanup(bpy.types.Operator): 
    '''Merge material slots and delete unnecessary ones'''
    
    # try naming your operators in a way that conforms to the usual conventions of blender
    # it helps keep things consistent and placed in a logical way relative to other operators
    bl_idname = 'object.material_slot_cleanup'
    bl_label = 'Material Clean Up Operator'
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        obj = bpy.context.scene.mainchar #object passed through from a PointerProperty
                
        # this operator is only reliant on the object being active.
        # you don't have to do anything changing it's select state.
        # so you can get rid of this part
        
        # bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        # bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        
        # you already have a reference to the active object from your PointerProperty. 
        # Use that instead of constantly reference bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
        
        # bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
                
        for mat in reversed(obj.material_slots):
            if mat.name not in mats_to_keep_mainchar:
                obj.active_material_index = mat.slot_index
                # you seem to be flip flopping between referencing the bpy.context.active_object
                # and then referencing your scene.mainchar object. I think your problem is that you need 
                # to stick with just one. Usually referencing bpy.context inside an operator is bad practice
                # best to refer to the context argument passed into the execute callback.
                # maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the operator but it seems like it's asking for trouble
                # bpy.context.object.active_material_index = mat.slot_index
                bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove() #removes the indices from the previously selected material slots

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Regarding the issues with the operator not working on non-mesh objects, you would need to just collect the objects into a list that match the target type, like:

```
objs_to_operate_on = [obj for obj in context.selected_objects if obj.type == 
"MESH"]
for obj in objs_to_operate_on:
    # do operator
```

That or you can put something in the poll method of your operator like:

```
@classmethod
def poll(self, context):
    return context.active_object.type != "EMPTY"
```

Or put something in your execute method, like:

```
obj = context.active_object
if obj.type != "MESH":
    self.report({"ERROR"}, "Active object must be type: 'MESH'")
    return {"CANCELLED"}
else:
    # do the thing
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am very confused with the distinction between active and selected object... (I) So: multiple objects can be selected, but always only one can be active, right? (II) I see you are "activating" the mainchar object, but based on docs, material_slot_remove() only works for the selected object so why would your approach work if I had a different object previously selected? (III) How do I reference "the context argument passed into the execute callback"? I am much appreciating your help!!

Comment: I mean reference the context that you see in the execute method of your Operator. Where it says `execute(self, context)`. Use that context, not `bpy.context`. The [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove) that I see for `material_slot_remove()` only say it affects the selected material slot, i don't see anything about the selected object. Usually operators work on the active object. So whatever object you want to remove the mats from you need to set `context.view_layer.objects.active` to that.